# roll up and open a page on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slide

What I'm trying to do is:

- after clicking the button, the part of the page (where the actual button is placed + some more items) are being rolled up (slided up) and after this is done
- the user is being taken to another page

The code I've done so far is the following (obviously not working):

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <p>something anything</p>
        ...
    </div>
<a id="roll"><img src="_images/butt-submit.png"></a>

</div>


<script>

$('#roll').click(function() {
     $('#content').animate({
          "width" : "100%",
          "height" : "0px"
         }, function() {
     $(this).load('index2.html');
        });
});

</script>
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### As [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2AhZt/) shows this should do the trick

```
$("#roll").click(function() {
     $("#content").animate({
          width: "100%",
          height: "0px"
     }, function() {
         window.location.href = "index2.html";
     });
});
```

But instead of using `animate`, you could as well just use `slideUp` and simplify your code:

```
$("#roll").click(function() {
     $("#content").slideUp(function() {
         window.location.href = "index2.html";
     });
});
```

​

### Why `location.href` and not just `location`?

As you can see I've used `window.location.href` while I could easily use just:

```
window.location = "index2.html";
```

This would work just as well and cross browser, but since `window.location` is an object it's more clear if you use a longer notation and target specific string property.

### Correct `script` block definition

As it seems you're also not providing script block language which is a requirements [as per HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2). First sentence says that it's a must:

> <sub>HTML 4.01</sub>
>   <sub>**18.2.2 Specifying the scripting language**</sub>
>
> *The type attribute **must** be specified for each SCRIPT element instance in a document.*

In your case that means that `script` blocks have to be provided with language otherwise they may not get recognised as script blocks in the first place:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

Comment: unfortunately this one didn't work for some reason. No action on click at all :(

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: I've created a JSFiddle that proves it works. I've used your HTML and my code with the additional replacement of `animate` with `slideUp`. **[Click here. Works.](http://jsfiddle.net/2AhZt/)** If it's not working on your page then check your console for javascript errors. You must have some other error in your scripts.

Comment: I will search for any problems in my code. thank you very much @RobertKoritnik. This is perfect.

Comment: I have done it this way here: [link](http://test.captive-portal.com/test2.html) but it doesn't work. it works in your link on http://jsfiddle.net. Why is that possible? I give up... :(

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: Try setting type to your `script` element so browsers will recognise it as javascript block. `type="text/javascript"`. As per spec you have to provide your script's language.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: don't give up so easily... :) [Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.2) says: *The type attribute **must** be specified for each SCRIPT element instance in a document.*

Comment: Thank you. I know what was the problem. While copying from Fiddle there appeared one ILLEGAL CHARACTER. That was the reason. thanks a lot. One more question. How can I delay it? When I have more content inside #content, it doesn't slideUp to the end. Just a little bit then it goes to another page. How can I make sure it goes up to the end?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19837/discussion-between-piotr-ciszewski-and-robert-koritnik)

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: function is always called when animation is completed. I guess that when you have enough content so that it becomes scrollable, then you're likely having browser issue because it's not just contracting elements but it also updates scrollbar etc. So it has much more to do and it can't keep up with animation. Try setting a long animation time to see whether redirection happens after completed animation: `...slideUp(5000, function() { ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load the page into the `content` element(*as you are using load method*), you can use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` methods, currently you are setting the `height` to 0 and you cannot see the loaded content.

```
$(function() { // when the DOM is ready
   $('#roll').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault() // prevent the default action of the event
       $('#content').slideUp(function() {
            $(this).load('index2.html', function(){ // when load is complete
               $(this).slideDown() // slide down the #content element 
            });
       });
   });
})
```

In case that you want to redirect the user to another page, you can use `window.location.href`, but why not using `href` attribute:

```
<a id="roll" href='index2.html'><img src="_images/butt-submit.png"></a>
```

Comment: exactly, like @RobertKoritnik mentioned, but this one partly worked. also when I applied this one - the empty div slided down, no content inside, however i believe it's a matter of different question. thanks anyway

Comment: I have applied this code, but again - after it's successfuly slided up, it slides down with an empty #content div. No redirection to index2.html. How can I finalize this? It's almost working

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski You are welcome, note that `load` loads the entire page, in case that you want to load specific element's content, first make sure the path is correct and then you can select that element to be loaded, you can code `$(this).load('index2.html #idOfAnElement')`

Comment: thank you for this. I will write it down for future, as it will definitely be useful. How can I open the whole page in the same window instead of loading elements from another one? I have added href to my <a>, but it still doesn't work. So basically i want the #content to slide up and then redirects everything to the new page, so new page open in the same window, like a normal url.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski You are welcome, as other answers mention, you can use `window.location.href = index2.html`, you can replace all the codes that are related to the `load` method and use the `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$(this).load('index2.html');
```

is for AJAX loading that second page into a DOM element (in this case `#roll`). If you want to take the user to another page, as you say, use:

```
window.location = 'index2.html';
```

Comment: @Diodeus I forgot `location` is a property, not a method -- too much jQuery in my head. Fixed.

Comment: @Blazemonger: that was likely the reason for the downvote. Because you've used location as a function. :) It wasn't me though. ;) I was busy typing my own answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

> the user is being taken to another page

In order to perform that task you should use:

```
location.href = "index2.html"
```